# why is Loadable Components throwing a requireAsync .then is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loadable-component

I'm trying to code-split a big file and have it lazily load async when needed.

Chrome dev tools is showing this error (see pic) when I try to click to the affected part of the webapp. Suggests I've not set something up properly, but i am following the docs and cant see much different.

My code is as folows:

routes.js - matches routes and returns react containers.
AsyncSignupPage.js - literally just imports Signup and makes it 'loadable' / async.
Signup.js - the actual signup page container.

routes.js:

```
const routes = [
   ...
   {
    component: () => <AsyncSignupPage />,
    path: "/signup/:page",
    exact: true
   }
   ...
]
```

AsyncSignupPage.js:

```
import React from "react";
import loadable from '@loadable/component';

const AsyncSignupPage = loadable(() => <div>This was lazily loaded</div>)

export default AsyncSignupPage;
```

I have left AsyncSignupPage just returning a div for now, as that alone creates this issue.

What am i doing wrong here?

[image: chrome error]